# How to change accordion button icon on class change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion

I want to change accordion button icon on class change.

What i have is a static icon.

[image]

When the accordion clicked it stays the same, i would like to change the "+" into "-".

when the current accodion tab is opened, the class change from

```
<div class="mk-accordion-single">
```

Into

```
<div class="mk-accordion-single current">
```

is it possible to change it ? and how do i do it, if it's possible.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of an actual example of your accordion working? Any frameworks used?

Comment: Actually i'm using virtual composer wp bakery for the accordion in wordpress.

Comment: change the content of the element  from '+' to '-' with transition effect. Let me know if it works or not.